# use Json Array in serializable

Tags: android, json, serialization

I am having trouble in passing serializable in bundle it gives
`Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object error`

this is my serializable file

```
public class ExampleClass implements Serializable {
private String id;
private String name;    
private JSONArray array;
}
```

this is how i'm passing bundle from adapter
  `final ExampleClass example=example.get(position);`

`Utility.startActivity(context,example);`

```
 public static void startActivity(Context context, Object object)         
{
Intent intent=new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
bundle.putSerializable(MainActivity.EXTRA_DATA, (Serializable) object);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

I'm able to use all the `getMethod()`

Comment: Obviously `JSONArray` is not `Serializable`

Comment: @Selvin anything that can be done to use array as it is?

Answer (score 1):

Define Parsed `ArrayList` in `ExampleClass.java` instead of `JSONArray`. Because `JSONArray` is not serialized object.

Ref: https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html